# Javascript - Call a Local Function / Property While in Global Scope

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have the following JavaScript

```
function myGlobalFunction(){
    function firstInnerFunction(){
         return "rainbows";
    }
    function secondInnerFunction(){
         function innerInnerFunction(){
               return "clouds";
         }
         return innerInnerFunction();
    }
    return firstInnerFunction(); //valid call
}
```

Is there anyway I can call firstInnerFunction() in the global scope?  If so(and better yet), can I go two levels down and call innerInnerFunction() from the global scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, no. JavaScript is function scoped, so everything inside is hidden from the outside. So in order to access the inner functions you'll need to expose them somehow.

Absolute simplest (but ugly) option is to do something like this:

```
var secondInnerCopy;

function myGlobalFunction(){
    function firstInnerFunction(){
         return "rainbows";
    }
    function secondInnerFunction(){
         function innerInnerFunction(){
               return "clouds";
         }
         return innerInnerFunction();
    }
    secondInnerCopy = secondInnerFunction;
    return firstInnerFunction(); //valid call
}

myGlobalFunction();
secondInnerCopy(); //valid (only after myGlobalFunction called though)
```

Better option would be to restructure into an object graph with functions:

```
var global = {
    myGlobalFunction: function(){
        return this.inner.firstInnerFunction(); //valid call
    },
    inner: {
        firstInnerFunction: function() {
            return "rainbows";
        },
        secondInnerFunction: function(){
            return this.inner.innerInnerFunction();
        },
        inner: {
            innerInnerFunction: function(){
               return "clouds";
            }
        }
    }
};

global.myGlobalFunction();
global.inner.inner.innerInnerFunction();
//etc...
```

Answer (score 2):

What are you trying to achieve in doing something like that? I would suggest something like the following:

```
var myGlobalFunction = { 
    var innerInnerFunction() { return "clouds"; }
    get firstInnerFunction() { return "rainbows"; }
    get secondInnerFunction() { return innerInnerFunction(); }
};
```

You can then call firstInnerFunction() with something like this:

```
myGlobalFunction.firstInnerFunction;
```

as for calling innerInnerFunction() from the global scope, myGlobalFunction.secondInnerFunction() will serve the same purpose as calling innerInnerFunction() directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a call to globalFunction to define firstInnerFunction, you can do that as follows

```
function globalFunction() {
    firstInnerFunction = function() { return "rainbows" ; } ;
}
```

For innerInner function, you can do as  follows

```
function globalFunction() {
    firstInnerFunction = function() { return "rainbows" ; } ;
    secondInnerFunction = function() {
        innerInnerFunction = function() { return "clouds" ; } ; }
}
```

Now you can do this

```
globalFunction() ; // defines firstInnerFunction and secondInnerFunction in the global scope
firstInnerFunction() ; // returns "rainbows"
secondInnerFunction() ; // defines innerInnerFunction
innerInnerFunction() ; // returns "clouds"
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this is possible, however I could be wrong.  You could do something like this to access the nested functions via the top level function.

```
function A(x) {
   function B(y) {
      function C(z) {
         alert(x + y + z);
      }
      C(3);
   }
   B(2);
}
A(1); // alerts 6 (1 + 2 + 3)
```

Another Example

```
function addSquares(a,b) {
   function square(x) {
      return x * x;
   }
   return square(a) + square(b);
}
a = addSquares(2,3); // returns 13
b = addSquares(3,4); // returns 25
c = addSquares(4,5); // returns 41
```

Check this link, it has some good information on functions and nested functions in Javascript.  [Javascript Function Scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope)

Answer (score 0):

I believe something like this would also work, though I like what Alconja did.

```
var myGlobalFunction = {
  firstInnerFunction: function(){
     return "rainbows";
  },
  secondInnerFunction : function(){
     var innerInnerFunction =  function(){
         return "clouds";
     }
     var inninnerFuncTwo = function(){
         return 'more stuff';
     }
     return {
      inn : innerInnerFunction,
      inn2: inninnerFuncTwo
      }
  }
}

myGlobalFunction.secondInnerFunction().inn();
myGlobalFunction.secondInnerFunction().inn2();
```